# Formatting postDate using the ElementAPI plugin

Tags: json, plugin-elementapi

Building a small AngularJS app and using the ElementAPI plugin for the first time.

I can set `'postDate' => $entry->postDate` which gives me

```
postDate : {
   date: "2015-12-10 07:04:02.000000",
   timezone_type: 3,
   timezone: "UTC"
}
```

as an example.

Now I can access this date in Angular by doing `{{note.postDate.date}}` but obviously it's just a string so I can't use any native Angular filters for formatting.

Is there a way I can access the postDate with a date format? What options do I have?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$entry->postDate` will give you the `postDate` property of the `EntryModel`, which itself is a `DateTime` object.

The JSON transformer will do its best to convert that object to JSON by returning its visible properties, which produces the JSON object in your example.

Angular has built-in date filters, but it requires the input data to be in a recognized format. So, what you really want in your JSON - rather than a representation of the whole `DateTime` object - is a more primitive value that Angular knows how to interpret as a date: You need a *timestamp*.

Luckily, you can easily access the timestamp of the PHP `DateTime` object in your transformer, like this:

```
'postDate' => $entry->postDate->getTimestamp() * 1000
```

*(We're multiplying the timestamp by 1000 because Angular wants the timestamp to represent milliseconds; PHP gives us the timestamp in seconds.)*

Then, in Angular you can use the date filter to change the format as desired, which in your front-end code would look something like: `{{ note.postDate | date:'medium' }}`

Comment: As an FYI - need to do 'postDate' => $entry->postDate->getTimestamp()*1000 as Angular needs the timestamp in milliseconds

Answer (score 2):

Anything you spit out of Craft is going to be a string until you convert it into javascript so it's "native" to Angular/Javascript. JSON is just a transport format. There's no [standard format](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Jan/06/JavaScript-JSON-Date-Parsing-and-real-Dates) for dates in JSON (which is a little counter intuitive!).

I would do something like:

```
$jsDate =  $entry->postDate->iso8601();
... // output as usual
```

8601 is a good format to get your date into that JS can convert. Then make that into a JS [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), something like:

```
var angularDate = new Date(whatever);
```

Comment: So is ```$jsDate = $entry->postDate.iso8601();``` happening in the ```config/elementapi.php``` then?

Comment: iso8601 a helper [method](https://craftcms.com/classreference/etc/dates/DateTime#iso8601-detail) in the DateTime class.  Since the Element API just extends Craft, anything you can call in Craft is fair game. ``postDate`` just happens to be a DateTime object which is why it works.

Comment: I don't think the dot accessor syntax will work in the context of the JSON transformer. The dot syntax is for Twig, whereas in PHP you'd want to use the arrow syntax, like `$jsDate =  $entry->postDate->iso8601()`

Comment: Oops, duh- fixed, thank you, Your answer is much better than mine!